# Updating instance variable values and ensuring private methods use them - Java

Tags: java, oop, setter, getter

I have constructed a class that will compute an equation based on private instance variables.

These variables may be updated using getter and setter methods, the latter of which are called and changed from a separate control class within the project (I am using Eclipse if that is relavant)

I need to ensure that the constructor uses the updated values when passed from the separate control class to the setter methods in computing variable c.

Here is snipets of my code.

instance variables

```
    private double a;
    private double b; 
    private double c;
```

constructor

```
public Prob(){
    a = 4; //must be first initialized with these values then later changed from the control class
    b = 10;
    setA(a);
    setB(b);
    setC();
```

setter methods

```
public void setA(double a){
    if(isValidA(a))
        this.a = a;
    else this.a = 100; // 100 is meaningless and allows execution of "invalid" string
            }
public void setB(double b){
    if(isValidB(b))
        this.b = b;
    else this.b = -1; // -1 is meaningless, allows execution "invalid entry" code in string
        }

private void setC(){
        if(a<=5 && b>=2)
             c = (int)(5 + 0.5*a - 5*(Math.pow(b, 0.2)) + 0.5*(a)*b;
       else c = a; 
}
```

I can update variable a or variable b from the control class but how can I get variable c to update as well based on the current a and b?

Comment: I have also searched quite extensively but I can not find a single example that demonstrates this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, then you could `setA` and `setB` like so

```
public void setA(double a) {
  this.a = (isValidA(a)) ? a : 100;
  setC(); // <-- call setC();
}
public void setB(double b) {
  this.b = (isValidB(b)) ? b : -1;
  setC(); // <-- call setC();
}
```

Comment: To add to this answer, `setC()` should have the logic to update the value of `c`. (Perhaps it would be better named`updateC()`?)

Comment: THANK YOU! AHHH I am beyond overjoyed. I understand your simpler method of calling the validating methods but obviously I have presented very edited and simplified code so I am unable to use it in my original code but I will keep this in mind for the future. Thank you. You have been a great help.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice the name of the setC() method is already given to me so I can't change or add to the name on the code within the curly brackets.

Answer (score 0):

If c depends on a and b, you should either call `setC` from `setA` and `setB`, or call `setC` after each time you call `setA` or `setB`.

The former would be cleaner to implement, but may cause redundant calculations (if you update both a and b at the same time, it would call setC twice).

The latter would be more efficient (since if you call both `setA` and `setB`, you can explicitelly call `setC` once after these two calls), but more bug prone (since you might forget to call `setC` in some of the places you call `setA` or `setB`).

Another option, which I think is the best, is to calculate c on demand in getC, and cache the result (so that following calls to `getC` won't have to recalculate its value, unless a or b are changed). In this case you don't need `setC`. You'll need to add a boolean member `cIsValid` that would be an indicator of whether the cached value of c is valid.

```
public double getC () 
{
  if (!cIsValid) {
       if(a<=5 && b>=2)
            c = (int)(5 + 0.5*a - 5*(Math.pow(b, 0.2)) + 0.5*(a)*b;
       else 
            c = a;
  }
  cIsValid = true;
  return c;
}
```

And in `setA` and `setB` you invalidate the cache by setting cIsValid to false :

```
public void setA(double a)
{
    if(isValidA(a))
        this.a = a;
    else 
        this.a = 100; // 100 is meaningless and allows execution of "invalid" string
    cIsValid = false;
}

public void setB(double b)
{
    if(isValidB(b))
        this.b = b;
    else 
        this.a = -1; // -1 is meaningless, allows execution "invalid entry" code in string
    cIsValid = false;
}
```

Comment: I know it doesn't make sense in my simple version but in my original program I use the values 100 and -1 which are outside the acceptable value ranges for variables a and b respectively to execute an "invalid entry" message to the user in my toString() method. I had a type but I fixed it. Thank you for your response though, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @EMMERZOH I updated the answer to use a boolean instead of -1 to invalidate c (after I realized -1 might be a valid value of c). Anyway, the last approach in my answer is more efficient than the other answer.

Comment: Ahh I see. I must use a getC() method to return the value of c unfortunately but I will keep this in mind for the future. Thank you so much!

Comment: @emmerzoh I didn't remove the getC method,  I removed setC and made the calculation of c more efficient.

Comment: Ohhh. I misunderstood. I still must have the setC() method. I am given a list of methods and variables, am told what they must do and must code accordingly. It's not overly complicated just a little tricky to get the logic right based on what is expected of me.